# How to detect object in ML C# using yolo v3 model (with two outputs)?

Tags: yolo, ml.net, pre-trained-model, onnx

I have `tiny yolo v3` pre-trained model and I want to use it in C#, in order to be able to detect objects.
I came across the following [working sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_ObjectDetection_Onnx) but the tutorial is made for a `tiny yolo v2` model with the properties: [image]

while my pre-trained model has the properties: [image: ![enter image description here]

So there is incompatibility not only in the names, but also in the number of outputs and in the parameters for inputs / outputs. Since ML is not my area, I am having difficulties in migrating the code to support this new model that I have.

What I did so far was:

- renaming all occurrences of the input param `image` into the value `000_net`
- renaming all occurrences of the output param `grid` into the value `016_convolutional`
- changes the values ([this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-onnx#create-the-parser))

from:

```
public const int ROW_COUNT = 13;
public const int COL_COUNT = 13;
public const int CHANNEL_COUNT = 125;
public const int BOXES_PER_CELL = 5;
public const int BOX_INFO_FEATURE_COUNT = 5;
public const int CLASS_COUNT = 20;
public const float CELL_WIDTH = 32;
public const float CELL_HEIGHT = 32;
```

into (based on the comments from person that provided me the model):

```
public const int ROW_COUNT = 13;
public const int COL_COUNT = 13;
public const int CHANNEL_COUNT = 18;
public const int BOXES_PER_CELL = 3;
public const int BOX_INFO_FEATURE_COUNT = 5;
public const int CLASS_COUNT = 1;
public const float CELL_WIDTH = 32;
public const float CELL_HEIGHT = 32;
```

Also I have replaced the class names, with the one class that the model is trained for.

In the final result after all my changes, the application is not throwing errors but it's showing warnings and the objects are not detected as they should. Here is the output that I got:

[image]

Warning says:

```
...
2020-08-25 14:46:40.5959296 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 022_convolutional_bn_bias appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
2020-08-25 14:46:40.5970795 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 022_convolutional_bn_mean appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
2020-08-25 14:46:40.5979695 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 022_convolutional_bn_var appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
2020-08-25 14:46:40.5988356 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 022_convolutional_conv_weights appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
2020-08-25 14:46:40.5996638 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 023_convolutional_conv_bias appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
2020-08-25 14:46:40.6006995 [W:onnxruntime:, graph.cc:863 onnxruntime::Graph::Graph] Initializer 023_convolutional_conv_weights appears in graph inputs and will not be treated as constant value/weight. This may prevent some of the graph optimizations, like const folding. Move it out of graph inputs if there is no need to override it, by either re-generating the model with latest exporter/converter or with the tool onnxruntime/tools/python/remove_initializer_from_input.py.
```

Comment: Interesting case... ApplyOnnxModel(...) takes an array of outputs. Have you tried that? https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/4bd6f19b6ccff856747598906350fee927f07bb3/src/Microsoft.ML.OnnxTransformer/OnnxCatalog.cs#L145